# Meaning of “flip the script”

Tags: meaning, phrases, verbs, nouns, slang

I’ve heard the phrase “flip your script” or “flip the script” in various hip-hop songs. What does it mean?

Comment: LQ question...LQ answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To turn a situation around by using what was said/done against you against the other. Maybe best understood like this: I am exchanging roles with my counterpart, taking on his part of the script.

There are possible explanations in the [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Flip%20The%20Script).

Answer (score 0):

You have knowingly done something wrong, yet have found a way to make the other party feel guilty instead.  In the positive version, you reveal that you are a winner, but you would generally thought to be a loser. You have turned the tables and 'flipped the script'.

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding a reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

**Flipping the Script**, urban slang: fabricating an elaborate offensive deceitful defence  of lies to throw attention off of them, turning the truth into a complete falsehood and using it against you... that's *flipping the script **on** you*.

Used to make a smoke screen to hide and deny the truth at the expense of another; purposely, intentionally lying to manipulate a situation to their advantage, even if it means completely lying and bombarding you with them; manipulating, confusing people who don't know the truth, quite convincingly. To concoct in order to deceive: completely fabricated an elaborate excuse or defence with outlandish implications and lies.

Answer (score 0):

It originates from the graffiti scene. Taking a rivals tag name and replicating it upside down or backwards. This shows disrespect for your rival and showcases your superior graffiti skills by demonstrating that the rivals "script" or "tag" is so simple that you can replicate it in any orientation. It evolved to mean taking control of a situation that you initially had no control over or to surprise an opponent by doing the unexpected.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: It originated from the graffiti scene. By taking a rival's tag and reproducing it upside down. Showing your superior skills by duplicating the tag but up side down or backward. Implying your rivals tag is basic by flexing and flipping the script.